# Why is $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] always GET?

Tags: php, forms

I'm a bit confused about this. I'm hoping it's something wildly obvious I've missed! I have a very simple form:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" name="login" method="POST" action="/page">
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>
```

**Note:** this page lives at `/page` and is echoed after the following HTML:

On `/page` I have this at the very top of the file:

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
```

For some reason, it **always** shows up as `GET` when I submit this form. If I take the `action="/page"` part out then it shows up as `POST`. What am I missing here?

**Note:** Even when I load the page, then put at exit after the above `var_dump()` call, it still shows `GET`.

In the inspector's timeline I see this for the request:

[image]

Comment: What is `action="/page"`? Doesn't look like a file path, how is it routed?

Comment: There is an index.php page in there. No .htaccess or any clever routing going on and there's no redirect cache or anything messing about.

Comment: I was about to say.  It looks like it is redirecting after *processing* the post request.  Can we see the `index.php`?

Comment: You need to have some kind of routing from your form to /page. That SHOULD return POST. I've tried it just in case using page.php instead of /page

Comment: Any change if you stipulate the action as `/page/index.php?`

Comment: In your network panel, after you submit the form, what do you see to `/page`?

Comment: I have just added some notes to clear up confusion. This is one single page (index.php) always referenced by /page.

Comment: It works for me when you change `action="/page"` to `action="/page/"`

Comment: Open up Firebug or whichever and tell us the `referrer` for the mystery `GET` request.

Comment: Can you specify more about the server setup? apache, nginx? the current configuration. Any proxy?

Comment: @Danijel Thanks, yes that works for me too. I'm adding more information to the question

Comment: I've figured this out thanks to everyone's observations and follow up questions and detailed in my answer. Thanks all!

Comment: Try replacing the file extension (i.e. ,php) with a forward slash (/). Worked for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to the comments to my question I have found the answer to be in apache configuration. It appears that, because the `index.php` file is inside a folder called `page`, apache will automatically redirect to the page with a slash on it. This is the default setting as seen in the Apache [directorySlash documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

As they warn against turning this off, I will just change the url to what I'm posting. Alternatively, of course, I could add a `.htaccess` file with proper rewrite rules setup.\

Thanks for everyone's help! As a side note, Safari's inspector left me a little wanting in this case. Chrome turned out to be a far better option for testing.

Comment: The answer before by Dist was the correct answer, even if you used a variant of the same solution.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't. It said it had to use /index.php but that's not true. Also, it didn't answer why it was happening, just a workaround.

Comment: It also happens in nginx.  It seems to send the request to PHP as a GET unless the trailing slash is supplied.  Very strange.