# PHP Server handling POST request as GET method

Tags: php, api, post, get, xampp

I have a really strange "bug" happening right now. I have a small API where I want to handle different methods, but when sending a POST request the server handles it as GET method. Here's my code:

```
<?php
  $C_Metodo = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
  $N_Estado = 200;
  $O_Estado = ["status" => $C_Metodo];

  http_response_code($N_Estado);
  echo json_encode($O_Estado);
?>
```

When sending a DELETE or another method the response is the right method, but when using POST it returns GET.

Postman sending POST request:
[image: Postman sending POST request]

Comment: Can we see any code ?

Comment: Be more specific if you want your question to be answered. What is the source code?

Comment: how are you sending the delete, or other methods? Seems like **importante** information to me.

Comment: How are you calling the code? How is the form, or whatever you're using, set up? Is that the whole PHP-code, or is there other code preceeding this?

Comment: You didn't give much information, but maybe because of a redirect? The same as this guy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506168/why-is-serverrequest-method-always-get

Comment: Yep, the same thing as the other question, never happpened before, thanks Antony, sadly i can't access to the config files of the PHP server.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and POSTMAN working fine and provide POST method in response.`

$C_Metodo = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

$N_Estado = 200;

$O_Estado = $C_Metodo;

var_dump($C_Metodo);
?>`

check with this script.